# Could the 144,000 of Rev 14:2-5 be the firstfruits of of the wheat harvest?

Tags: second-coming

Could the 144,000 of Rev 14:2-5 be the firstfruits of of the wheat harvest?

"These were redeemed from among men, being firstfruits to God and to the Lamb." Rev 14:4

Could the alive tribulation believers be the "left" (aphiemi, 863 "(II) To let go from one's power, let escape (Matt 24:40, 41; Luke 17:34-36)" as described by Jesus in Matthew 24 and Luke 17 end-time parables?

"The Feast of Weeks" - "And you shall count for yourselves from the day after the Sabbath, from the day hat you brought the sheaf of the wave offering: seven Sabbaths shall be completed. Count fifty days to the day after the seventh Sabbath; then you shall offer a new grain offering to the LORD. You shall bring from your dwellings two wave loaves of two-tenths of an ephah. They shall be of fine flour; they shall be baked with leaven. They are the firstfruits to the LORD." Lev 23:15-17

"The priest shall wave them with the bread of the firstfruits as a wave offering before the LORD ..." Lev 23:20

Ref: NKJV, Interlinear, The Complete WordStudy Dictionary New Testament, ISBN 0-89957-663-X

Comment: DV: An answer to a question shouldn't be the question. This isn't a message board where you're starting a discussion. You've posted a lot of really poorly framed or self answered, within the question, questions. Take some time and look at the higher voted for questions and see how they're formatted. Glad to have you here, I just want things to stay high quality.

Comment: It is quite permissible to ask a question and then (usually after waiting a day or two to allow other users to assimilate and respond) to answer one's own question. But doing both together is, at the very least, impolite.

Comment: To avoid having you questions closed or ignored, please ask questions only.  You may answer your own question but not in the question.  This is not a discussion site it is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

Before this question can be answered, the identity of this group of 144,000 people of all the tribes of Israel, said to be sealed unto God with his name in their foreheads (chapter 7) must be made clear. It is not until chapter 14 that we get more details, now they are in heaven. Their symbolic sealing is repeated, they are singing a new song, unique to them, virgins etc, then comes the bit you ask about - What does their being 'firstfruits' to God and to the Lamb mean?

Given that the whole book of Revelation is symbolic, and that consistency in interpretation of the visions is required, we can assume that the number is not literal, the 'sealing in their foreheads' is not literal, their being 'virgins' is not literal, and that they are not literally picked up and 'waved' in heaven, as how a firstfruit sheaf of wheat was, in old testament times.

You have provided your own interpretation, which means I'm wasting my time providing this one, but I shall simply quote from a book that gives a different one. It is established that Christ is the one who does this reaping, because they are his own - they are firstfruits unto him, the Lamb, and to God. He precedes the angel sent to reap the wicked vine of the earth, for trampling. Just before that happens, Christ's firstfruits are safely gathered in (Rev.14:14-20).

> "As to the one hundred and forty-four thousand, this figure evidently
> answers to twelve multiplied by twelve. Twelve being the number of the
> patriarchs of the children of Israel, as well as of the apostles of
> our Lord Jesus Christ, evidently the number points to the multiplied
> elect from both old and new testaments.
>
> Twelve is the number of the covenant. There are twelve gates in the
> wall of the holy city, new Jerusalem, having the names of the twelve
> tribes of the children of Israel. This indicates the covenant people
> of God's choice out of every tribe obtaining entrance by grace into
> the heavenly city, that is, through faith in the gospel preached
> before unto Abraham their father.
>
> Likewise the wall of the city had twelve foundations, and in them the
> names of the twelve apostles of the Lamb. This is indicative of the
> new testament, or new covenant, for by the twelve apostles the
> doctrine of Christ was both preached and taught. Thus all the chosen
> people of God under the new covenant continue steadfast in the
> apostles' doctrine and fellowship, being built upon one foundation,
> which is Jesus Christ. Such a people are multiplied under the
> preaching of the word. Thus, as one together with their old testament
> brethren, the complete number is signified by the allegorical figure
> of one hundred and forty-four thousand." (*The Revelation of Jesus
> Christ*, pp.343-344, John Metcalfe)

Of course, anyone taking that number as literal will dismiss all the foregoing. But before understanding what 'firstfruits' means, as applying to that group, their identity must be correctly established.

> "The harvest is the end of the world. This concept cannot change. But
> there are two distinct applications of that harvest... the gathering
> of the redeemed is put first... Hence it is the firstfruits unto God
> and to the Lamb, reaped in person by one like unto the Son of Man. For
> these are his own firstfrutis out of the one great harvest... These
> are the redeemed from among men, rapturously taken up from the earth
> and brought home to be for ever with the Lord'... The other -
> virtually simultaneously - was the remainder of the harvest, being
> reaped by the angel, and consigned to the winepress of the wrath of
> God. One harvest, the harvest at the end of the world, but two
> reapings." (*Ibid*. pp.360-361)

This is where clarity needs to come as to the distinction between the old testament first-ripe sheaf brought in - a harbinger of the whole harvest, seven weeks later. (See pp 403-406 of that book.) Application is made to Jesus being cut off from the earth on the cross, and the gap until that Day of Pentecost.

> "Whatever was true of that firstripe sheaf, must be true of the whole
> harvest. Hence, as the firstripe sheaf was carefully gathered by being
> put to the sickle, the harvest of that from which the firstripe sheaf
> was taken must likewise be reaped... Rev.14:16; Mat.3:12 & 13:30. 'The
> harvest is the end of the world', Matthew 13:39...
>
> That another - and distinct - angel of judgment came out of the temple
> which is in heaven, *after* 'the earth was reaped' Rev. 14:16; and
> reaped by one like unto the Son of man as opposed to angels; and that
> this other angel had in  his hand - yet to be employed - another sharp
> sickle, of the same kind as that with which one like unto the Son of
> Man had already reaped the firstfruits, argues beyond all reasonable
> doubt *another, a further reaping*, even in that same day of the
> Lord.... This implies that the wheat harvest, as opposed to the
> *gathering* of the grapes of the vine of the earth, is an entirely separate event: the two representing as different a form in
> agriculture, as do the sheep and the goats in nature." (*Ibid.*
> pp.406-407)

**Summary:**  Jesus' being lifted up from the earth on the cross, then going to heaven, represented the first sheaf cut as a guarantee of the whole harvest that would take place seven weeks later. Christ starts the one harvest at the end of the world by gathering to himself all who belong to him, immediately before an angel does the second, fatal reaping of the vine of the earth. One harvest, two reapings. The one hundred and forty-four thousand symbolise all the redeemed who are safely gathered in, to be presented before God and Christ in heaven, just before the wicked are gathered, trampled, and burned.

Comment: Anne - Thank you for your insightful answer. A couple of points. " the gathering of the redeemed is put first", if this means the "caught up" dead and alive believers of 1Th 4:15-17, John 14:3, Rev 7:9, then I agree. I suggest that the angels of Mat 13 are reapers v39 that gather "First gather together the tares" ... "but gather the wheat into my barn." And they "separate the wicked from among the Just."

Comment: Anne - I also suggest that Jesus resurrected was the firstfruits of the Feast of Unleavened Bread., This feast represented sinless (unleavened) to the Jews. Paul described Christ as "firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep." 1Cor 15:20.

Comment: @hank  I won't go into further details because it can take a book to thrash out the reasons for any particular interpretation. Your phrase "dead and alive tribulations Jews" under your Q show that we are not on the same spiritual wavelength, or time-line here. But I have no desire to argue with you, and thank you for the opportunity to post an answer.

Comment: Anne - Fair enough ...  but in my defense I meant no disrespect by using the terms "dead and alive tribulation Jews." The believing dead and alive Jews were "caught up" along with the believing dead and alive gentiles and were taken to heaven by the Lord. 1Th 4:15-17, 1th 3:13b; John 14:3 and Rev 7:9